# Can DATE_PART be used in HAVING clause?

Tags: sql

When the following SQL query is executed, it seems that the HAVING clause doesn't take any effect.

```
SELECT
   day_of_week,
   fc,
   gl,
   CASE WHEN COUNT(inbound_allocation_factors) IS null THEN 0 ELSE count(inbound_allocation_factors) END AS num_of_factors,
   DATE(request_datetime) AS date
FROM 
     allocationworkflow_with_gl
GROUP BY day_of_week,fc,gl,date
HAVING day_of_week = DATE_PART(dw,MAX(request_datetime))
```

request_datetime is a timestamp, and day_of_week is integer from 0 to 6 indicating Sunday to Saturday. By the way, I'm using Redshift. Could anyone help me? Many thanks!

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or Amazon?  They are very different.

Comment: Given the fields in your GROUP BY, I would expect the HAVING clause to do nothing as well.  Your GROUP BY is grouping by the field you're aggregating on `request_datetime`.  It doesn't matter that you're grouping by date without time, the day of the week is only dependent on the date.  That will always appear to do nothing.  Can you explain what your query is supposed to do?

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff   It's Amazon Redshift, not SQL server.

Comment: @ Bacon Bits In the table allocationworkflow_with_gl, there is one column called request_datetime, which is a timestamp up-to-the second. I wanna count how many rows are there on each day, then select the count for the latest day. I don't wanna use a sub query in where clause, that's why I tried having clause.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not `datepart()`.  Your problem is the `day_of_week` with no aggregation.  You can validate this by doing:

```
HAVING DATE_PART(dw, MAX(request_datetime)) = 1
```

I'm not sure what you really want to do, but this answers your immediate question.

Comment: Thanks for your help,  but the program will run once a day so the day of the week will change and can not hard code it to be 1.